# How to get private Keys from Wallet using bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core

```
createwallet "MyWallet"
getwalletinfo
{
  "walletname": "MyWallet",
  "walletversion": 169900,
  "format": "bdb",
  "balance": 0.00000000,
  "unconfirmed_balance": 0.00000000,
  "immature_balance": 0.00000000,
  "txcount": 0,
  "keypoololdest": 1617197424,
  "keypoolsize": 1000,
  "hdseedid": "4da0242dbf5124f4f05e6ffaf6bd94c51a9d7858",
  "keypoolsize_hd_internal": 1000,
  "paytxfee": 0.00000000,
  "private_keys_enabled": true,
  "avoid_reuse": false,
  "scanning": false,
  "descriptors": false
}
```

But I don't know what to do next. A lot of commands are deprecated.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There are commands to get the private keys, but generally this isn't something you should do. What do you need them for?

Comment: I need to be able to Send / Receive BTC using my own software.

Comment: By using Bitcoin-Qt, or something else?

Comment: I am testing with Bitcoin-QT using a private node now. Eventually will be using BTCPayServer

Comment: NVM, I have found the answer it is ``dumpprivkey``